# CustomScriptExtension failed with "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I'm using CustomScriptExtension with ManagedIentity and sometimes it fails with

```
\"Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: Operation is not valid due to the current state of
the object.\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at
https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "
```

What does this error really mean?

Answer (score 1):

Every time I've hit it, with ManagedIdentity, what it actually meant was 'there's nothing there to download because you uploaded the script blobs to the wrong container'.

Comment: Like Tim Lovell-Smith said, in my particular case the casing was wrong, Test.ps1 vs test.ps1.